# why does the twolot list split not work in my code, it should be qorking, please can someone explani why?

Tags: python

```
subjects1 = ("1. Physics\n2. Chemistry\n3. History\n4. Geography\n5. Computer Science")
Physics = []
Chemistry = []
History = []
Geography = []
Computer_science = []
subjects = [Physics, Chemistry, History, Geography, Computer_science]
too_little = []
okay = []
onelot = []
twolot = []
twolottwo = []
twolotthree = []
toomuch = []
x = 1
def data_entry(times):
    while times > 0:
        times = times-1
        name = input("Please enter the name of the student")
        print(subjects1)
        x = int(input("Please enter the number choice of what the first subject the student has chosen is"))
        z = int(input("Please enter the number choice of what the second subject the student has chosen is"))
        class_dict = {1:Physics, 2:Chemistry, 3:History, 4:Geography, 5:Computer_science,}
        class_dict[x].append(name)
        class_dict[z].append(name)
    for i in subjects:
        if len(i) < 10:
            too_little.append(i)
        elif len(i) < 40 and len(i) > 20:
            okay.append(i)
            num = len(i) / 2
            print(num)


            onelot = okay[:int(num)]
            twolot = okay[int(num):]
            print(onelot)
            print(twolot)


    #print(Physics, Chemistry, History, Geography, Computer_science)
    print("The amount of people who have chosen Physics is:", len(Physics))
    print("The amount of people who have chosen Chemistry is:", len(Chemistry))
    print("The amount of people who have chosen History is:", len(History))
    print("The amount of people who have chosen Geography is:", len(Geography))
    print("The amount of people who have chosen Computer Science is:", len(Computer_science))

def main():
    p = int(input("How many students would you like to enter"))
    data_entry(p)

main()
```

that is my code, i dont understand why the list split doesnt work, the output for when i print one onelot this happens

```
[['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']]
```

whereas when i print twolot this is the output

```
[]
```

this is wrong as half the 1s should be in the second list surely 
thanks

Comment: `subjects` is a string... do you expect it to be a list?

Comment: @BallpointBen subjects is list of list not strings.

Comment: You're appending in the okay array, the value i, where i is should be the name of the students divided by subject, that's why you have string... What's suppose to be your output for onelot and twolot?

Comment: You are getting strings because you are appending `name` which isnot converted to int

Answer (score 0):

As an aside:

```
    if x == 1:
        Physics.append(name)
    if x == 2:
        Chemistry.append(name)
    if x == 3:
        History.append(name)
    if x == 4:
        Geography.append(name)
    if x == 5:
        Computer_science.append(name)
    if z == 1:
        Physics.append(name)
    if z == 2:
        Chemistry.append(name)
    if z == 3:
        History.append(name)
    if z == 4:
        Geography.append(name)
    if z == 5:
        Computer_science.append(name)
```

could be more cleanly written as such:

```
class_dict = {1:Physics, 2:Chemistry, 3:History, 4:Geography, 5:Computer_science,}
class_dict[x].append(name)
class_dict[z].append(name)
```

But the comments are correct, `name` is not an int, which is why your lists have strings

I think you want to change:

```
onelot = okay[0:int(num)]
twolot = okay[int(num):len(i)]
```

into:

```
onelot = okay[:int(num)]
twolot = okay[int(num):]
```

Comment: And assuming that this code will grow with time, you might want to define a class `Subject` containing the list of enrolled students, as well as functionality to determine if there are enough enrollments to allow course commencement. Just a thought.